# Postgres jsonb get by dynamic path

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Is it possible to do something like this in Postgres:

```
do $$
declare
  v_key text;
  v_json jsonb;
begin
  v_key := 'id';
  v_json := jsonb_build_object(
    'id', jsonb_build_object('nest_id',1)
  );
  raise notice '%', v_json #> '{'||v_key||'}'->>'nest_id';
end$$
```

> ERROR: operator does not exist: jsonb #> text
>    No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: `'{'||v_key||'}'::jsonb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right operand type of [the operator `#>`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) is text array. Use `array[...]` notation:

```
raise notice '%', v_json #> array[v_key] ->> 'nest_id';
```

or explicitly cast a formatted array literal:

```
raise notice '%', v_json #> ('{'||v_key||'}')::text[] ->> 'nest_id';
-- or nicer
raise notice '%', v_json #> format('{%s}', v_key)::text[] ->> 'nest_id';
```